# Shell script to verify data packages

Tags: macos, function, shell, unix

I need to make shell script to check my algorithms with loads of data(tests packages saved in .in files, every package contains folder with .in file and the other one with .out file where supposed to be correct result)
Sometimes It's about 1000 files in one packages so there's no point of doing it manually. I need some kind of loop which opens this .in file then redirect input of my c++ program and also redirect output of this program(save result to .out files) But the point is I can't get this language as quick as I need.
And I would like this script to compare results of my algorithm to .out files from packages

```
for f in ExternalIn/*.in; do//part of code which opens process with my algorithm and compare its .out file to .out file from package
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skipping checks for missing files, whitespace-safety, etc., you probably need something like:

```
for f in ExternalIn/*.in; do
    # diff the result of my_cpp_app eating file.in with file.out
    # and store the comparison result in file.diff
    diff ${f/.in/.out} <(my_cpp_app <$f 2>/dev/null) > ${f/.in/.diff}
done
```

Although I would probably do it with `find` / `xargs` pipeline which is not only safer but also allows parallel execution.

Or even write a `Makefile` for this and use `make`, which after all is a tool for exactly this kind of work.